# How to access variable parent scope from an event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following piece of code to retrieve a Wikipedia infobox:

```
function foo() {
    var searchTerm = "Something...";
    var bnameonly = "Something else...";    
    var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=" + searchTerm + "&redirects&prop=text&callback=?";
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        if (typeof(data.parse) !== 'undefined') {
            wikiHTML = data.parse.text["*"];
            $wikiDOM = $("<table>" + wikiHTML + "</table>");
            infobox = $wikiDOM.filter('.infobox.biota');
            $("#wiki").contents().find('#myinfobox').html(infobox);
        } else {
            var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=" + bnameonly + "&redirects&prop=text&callback=?";
            $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                if (typeof(data.parse) !== 'undefined') {
                    wikiHTML = data.parse.text["*"];
                    $wikiDOM = $("<table>" + wikiHTML + "</table>");
                    infobox = $wikiDOM.filter('.infobox.biota');
                    $("#wiki").contents().find('#myinfobox').html(infobox);
                }
            });
        }    
    });
}
```

However, if the first query fails (detected by `typeof(data.parse) == 'undefined'` being `true`) then the `else` clause should be executed. The problem is that the `bnameonly` variable is `undefined` at that point even when it has been declared in the parent environment.

Comment: Given your code sample, `bnameonly` will be accessible in both code blocks. Are you sure you've defined it in a global location in your actual working code?

Comment: Ouch. Callbacks within callbacks. You should look into what promises are.

Comment: `bnameonly` looks like is in global scope. It should work like this. I have a feeling that you did not post original source code.

Comment: Hi @Michal, you were right. Indeed the code is part of a function. So I've edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: What is `that`? From the looks of it you are missing `var that = this;`.

Comment: And does it work now? :)

Comment: Sorry @uom-pgregorio the 'that' was a leftover from a suggested solution I've found somewhere else but it didn't work.

Comment: **`if`** `(typeof(data.parse) !== 'undefined') {`...  **`else {`**... **`if`(typeof(data.parse) !== 'undefined') {`???**... So if not A, then if not A...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only check to see if the HTML is empty after you know the response has come back from the server (regardless of if it succeeded or failed). You can use jQuery's always method on it's jqXHR to test for this.

```
function foo() {
    var searchTerm = "Something...";
    var bnameonly = "Something else...";    
    function  myCallback(data) {
       ...
    }

    var url="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=" + searchTerm + "&redirects&prop=text&callback=?";   
    $.getJSON(url,{data})
       .done(myCallback)
       .always(function() {
          //executed only after $.getJSON succeeds or fails
          if ($("#wiki").contents().find('#myinfobox').html() === '') {
            var url="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=" + bnameonly + "&redirects&prop=text&callback=?";
            $.getJSON(url, {data}, myCallback);
          }
       })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the answers I've found in this other forum (https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-do-i-access-json-data-outside-of-getjson), I've found a solution by using a callback function:

```
function foo() {
    var searchTerm = "Something...";
    var bnameonly = "Something else...";
    function myCallback(data) {
        if (typeof(data.parse) !== 'undefined') {
            wikiHTML = data.parse.text["*"];
            $wikiDOM = $("<table>"+wikiHTML+"</table>");
            infobox = $wikiDOM.filter('.infobox.biota');
            $("#wiki").contents().find('#myinfobox').html(infobox);
        } else {
            $("#wiki").contents().find('#myinfobox').html('');
        }
    }

    var url="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=" + searchTerm + "&redirects&prop=text&callback=?";   
    $.getJSON(url, {data}, myCallback);

    if ($("#wiki").contents().find('#myinfobox').html() === '') {
        var url="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=" + bnameonly + "&redirects&prop=text&callback=?";
        $.getJSON(url, {data}, myCallback);

    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong because your first `$.getJSON` is asynchronous and you are checking the contents of `$('#wiki')` before it is finished, so your second `$.getJSON` will **always** be executed (look at your network requests and you'll see this is the case). As the other commenters have pointed out, there's no reason why your original code should fail (i.e. why `bnameonly` isn't available in your else). However, I have a feeling you're not showing us all the code and it's because you don't understand how asynchronous calls work. Are you trying to `return` anything from `foo` by any chance?

Comment: Hi @Adam, thanks. I'm not pretending to return anything from foo() function but just to update an infobox. I would appreciate if you can show the correct way to do it then? By the way, I've made small changes to detect an empty infobox (see the edited version).

Comment: See my answer below, you can't check in the lines after your first `$.getJSON` to see if the html is present, because it will never have been returned from the server at that point. What you need to do is to check if the HTML is empty after you know the request has succeeded or failed. See my answer below.

Comment: Hi @Adam, thanks. But I cannot see any answer below. Sorry, now I get it was above (my bad) :).